# Python Data frame: I want to add a new column based on the result of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, conditional-statements

I have a "Date" column & "Time" column.

I want to create a new column "Tradedate" & depending on the following condition:

If "Time" = 23:00:00, then add one day to "Date" and return result in "Tradedate" column, otherwise return"Date" result in "Tradedate" column

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2021/01/01","2021/01/01","2021/01/02"], "Time": ["22:00:00","23:00:00","00:00:00"]})

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df.info()

def trade_date(convert):
    
    for x in convert:
        if x == "23:00:00":
            return df["Date"] + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
        else: 
            return df["Date"] 
 
#df["Tradedate"] = df["Time"].apply(trade_date)

df["Tradedate"] = trade_date(df["Time"])
           
#trade_date(df["Time"])
```

Why doesn't my function work?
I instead get just the initial date as opposed to date +1 when time = 23:00:00

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Please simplify the code like below. I hope it works as u want.

**Code:**

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
def trade_date(row):
    if row["Time"] == "23:00:00":
        return (row["Date"] + pd.DateOffset(days=1)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    else:
        return row["Date"].strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

df["Tradedate"] = df.apply(trade_date, axis=1)
df["Date"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         Date      Time   Tradedate
0  2021/01/01  22:00:00  2021/01/01
1  2021/01/01  23:00:00  2021/01/02
2  2021/01/02  00:00:00  2021/01/02
```

Comment: @cathal if you like the solution and if you upvote and/or accept it, I'll be pleased, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) condition:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2021/01/01","2021/01/01","2021/01/02"], "Time": ["22:00:00","23:00:00","00:00:00"]})

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

df["Tradedate"] = df["Date"].where(df['Time'] != "23:00:00", df['Date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=1))

df
        Date      Time  Tradedate
0 2021-01-01  22:00:00 2021-01-01
1 2021-01-01  23:00:00 2021-01-02
2 2021-01-02  00:00:00 2021-01-02
```

Note that the logic is "*Replace values where the condition is False*" (emphasis on False...).